# Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I got the script to create a simple forum from someone. However I have a problem when going to install it.

Next image database and config php script
[image]

[image]

For those who understand please give the information.

Comment: `Access denied for user` pretty much explains it.

Comment: Your logins not match with server logins

Comment: @frz- Sorry, but I have not found the answer

Comment: Maybe you are using wrong username/password OR username that you are using doesn't have privilege to use that database OR incorrectly binding address to the user. Check the `PRIVILEGE` for the username.

Comment: @staff - I do not understand. I logged on cpanel. name_domain.com/cpanel

Comment: are you connecting locally ? check grand privilege settings in server

Comment: Are you sure that the user is named 'username' and his password is 'password'? Check it in the control panel, you can create a new user too. And if you didn't change any default configuration just try with 'root' (for username and password, or root and blank password).

Comment: @SigitPurnomo you need use logins from cPanel

Comment: @frz - Perhaps, if the password should be written like this phwppekg_password ..?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: It sounds like a permission issue. If you have a specific user/password for this database, you need to grant privileges to this user via `GRANT ALL ON <db>.<table(s)> TO '<username>'@'<ip>' [IDENTIFIED BY '<password>']` Keep in mind that you don't need the `IDENTIFIED BY` if you have no password for the user.

Comment: @robert - thank you, but the code is placed where? in the config.php

Comment: You execute this in mysql. This is all done on the database-side. Please refer to this [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for more information on it.

Comment: @robert still confused :)

Comment: Localhost, user root password empty

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the connection and database select as variables and then put the variable for connection into the database select.

```
$server="server name";
$username="username for database";
$password="password for database";
$connect_mysql=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("Connection Failed!");
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("database name",$connect_mysql) or die ("Could not Connect to Database");
```

and so on. If that doesn't work, try what frz3993 says with the privileges.